# what is cameraPosition in threejs GLSL?

Tags: three.js, glsl

I see some three.js shader code online which reads:

```js
vCameraPosition = cameraPosition;
```

Where does cameraPosition come from, and where in the API can I learn about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in uniforms and attributes of are defined in `WebGLProgram`. Check out the following doc page for more information.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram

Answer (score 0):

It's a vec3 containing the world space camera position of the camera you are rendering from.